# Android: Determine when the audio for a notification stops playing

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I'm using NotificationCompat.Builder to configure and build a notification with a custom sound using NotificationCompat.Builder.setSound(). How can I determine when the sound has stopped playing?

Comment: I could get the duration of the audio file and setup a timer, but I'm looking for something closer to an onCompletionListener if it exists.